# HTMLUnit scrape WebSocket page

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have page with source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=600, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Binary Options Platform</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/ext-theme-binary-options.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/app.css">

    <script src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="resources/js/chart/iecanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

</head>
<body>
<noscript>You must enable javascript to continue</noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {} else {
            var ifrm = document.createElement('IFRAME');
            ifrm.setAttribute("src", 'http://www.browserupgrade.info/ie6-upgrade/?lang=en&amp;title=www.dukascopy.com&amp;gc=true&amp;more-info-at=http://www.browserupgrade.info');
            ifrm.style.width = '100%';
            ifrm.style.height = '81px';
            ifrm.style.border = 'none';
            ifrm.frameBorder = 0;
            document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I tried to get it's content using HTMLUNIT for Java;

```
try {
            HtmlPage startPage = webClient.getPage("https://demo-login.dukascopy.com/binary/");
            System.out.println("PAGE: \n"+startPage.asText());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The problem is that I got only:

> PAGE:
>  Binary Options Platform

How to get page source in HtmlUnit for this website?

Answer (score 0):

use `startPage.asXml()` or  `startPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()` , if its fails you may have to access via `webWindows()`